# Choice of Origin in Multipole Expansion in Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, reference-frames, conventions, multipole-expansion

In a multipole expansion in electrostatics, how do we select the origin? For instance, if there is a linear continuous distribution of charge $+Q$ (say from $x = -a$ to $x = +a$). Is there any rule such as: midpoint ($z$ = Zero in this case). For opposite charges does it have to be the centre of the charge distribution where effective charge = zero?

Comment: You can do a multipole expansion about any point you want. There is normally an obvious choice of origin e.g. because it's a point with high symmetry, but the choice of origin is entirely up to you.

Comment: For a linearly distributed +Q charge, if we do multipole expansion, we do get dipole, quadrupole etc. terms. Does this mean that those terms come from the viewpoint of superposition of potentials due to (crudely termed imaginary) dipoles/quadrupoles etc. ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The multipole expansion of a field is the fields you'd get from an ideal dipole, quadrupole, octopole, etc. The total field is the sum of all these separate fields.